# Using Selectors in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I know you can do something like `input:not([type=text])` etc ..

I want to get all input fields of type text except one with an `id = 'x'`.

Is it possible with selectors?

Comment: Did you want a plain vanilla JavaScript answer, or are you using jQuery?

Comment: was using jquery! thanks ! sorry my bad, ambiguous question...

Answer (score 2):

Sure, try `$('input[type="text"]:not("#x")')`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uZbrm/)**

Comment: Why jQuery and not querySelectorAll?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - My mistake, I didn't see that was JS only. Actually, re-reading the question, the `input:not([type=text])` made me think jQuery. I left the OP a comment asking if he's using jQuery. If not, I'll delete.

Comment: @j08691, I am using jquery and am interested as well in the jquery method. However ŠimeVidas answer was spot on, just what I requested!

Comment: @j08691 Made you think jQuery, OK. But it's a plain CSS selector: http://jsfiddle.net/pNJU2/. `input[type=text]:not(#x)` is also a valid CSS selector, meaning all of these are compatible with querySelectorAll.